# How much does the distance between electron orbits shrink as proton number increases?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, protons

I was watching a YouTube video that briefly mentioned the electromagnetic attraction between the nucleus and it's electrons increases as the proton count of an atom increases. I'd never considered this to be the case, and just assumed electrons are always the same distance away from the nucleus depending upon the orbitals.

I would prefer to compare between the heaviest and lightest elements, but since Oganesson and the other superheavy elements aren't stable I can't imagine anyone would be able to answer questions about their orbital radii.

Instead, if I were to compare the **1s** orbital radius of Hydrogen and the **2s** orbital radius of Uranium, how much would those occupying electrons be affected in terms of distance from the nucleus due to increased electric charge within the nucleus? Uranium has 92 protons, which is 91 protons greater than Hydrogen, and an additional 91 electrons.

I can't really wrap my head around what's going on because the presence of more electrons, in my understanding, should cause the orbitals on the outside to get farther away from the nucleus. Is there a middle ground somewhere between the electro-repulsion and electro-attraction?

Comment: In the Bohr model the radius scales as $n^2/Z$.

Comment: Electrons in outer shells roughly feel the nuclear charge “screened” (i.e., reduced) by the charge of the electrons in the inner shells.

Comment: Compare the atomic radii of the elements of $\text{Group 1}$.

Comment: The Bohr results is only quantitatively applicable to "hydrogen-like" atoms (meaning one electron). But they are qualitatively applicable over a wider range of circumstances allowing for screening effects (in particular closed-shell + 1 atoms).